# How does Inquisitor's Flail interact with Trample?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Lets say I am attacking with a [Runeclaw Bear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221893) with an [Inquisitor's Flail](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222196) equipped.  My opponent uses a Runeclaw Bear of his own to block.  I then use [Kessig Wolf Run](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233256) to give my creature +3/+0 and trample.

How much damage can I deal my opponent in this scenario?

[image][image][image]

Comment: +1 for a good question.  Ian's answer is correct, but in the mists of time, I believe things worked a different way - a Trampler would deal damage to a blocking creature, and then excess damage would be somehow redirected to the defending player... and as such a card like Inquisitor's Flail (or Furnace of Rath, back in the day) might effectively double the damage twice!  Things are a lot simpler and better the way they work now, I think.

Comment: @thesunneversets - things definitely work better now , especially the interaction between deathtouch and trample.  I do kind miss the days when lifelink stacked though....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inquisitor's Flail doesn't let you assign damage any differently, it is merely a replacement effect for how damage is dealt.  So essentially, you have a 5/2 trampling Runeclaw Bear up against a regular 2/2 Runeclaw Bear.  You must assign lethal damage to the blocking Runeclaw before you can assign any damage to the defending player, so you can only assign a maximum of 3 to the defending player.  When damage is dealt, Inquisitor's Flail doubles everything, resulting in 4 being dealt to each Runeclaw Bear, and 6 being dealt to the defending player.